# Incorrect Usage. flag needs an argument: -rpcaddr = Ethereum private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private

I'm trying to make Ethereum private blockchain. But facing a error while running this

"geth --nodiscover --networkid 42 --datadir .ethereum/ --unlock 0x526d8a6baa472da27215f748236af96bc9f256d7--mine --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3 --rpcaddr"

While the error I'm getting is

"Incorrect Usage. flag needs an argument: -rpcaddr"

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation (haven't practice for a while)

```
 --rpcaddr value        HTTP-RPC server listening interface (default: "localhost")
```

You need to pass the address on witch one your rpc endpoint must be listenning. If I remember well, it corresponds to the IP address authorized to send commands.

By default, it is your localhost.

To allow everyone, use 0.0.0.0.

```
--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0
```

To allow a specific IP within your network (lets say 192.168.1.15):

```
--rpcaddr 192.168.1.15
```